# Count array instances in struct

Tags: c++

I have a struct datatype. It contains a data member that is also a struct.

```
struct List{
    private:
        struct Line listLine[MAX_LINES];
    public:
        void set(int no);
        void display() const;
};
```

`listLine` is of Line type, defined as:

```
struct Line {
    private:
        int num;
        char itemString[MAX_CHARS + 1];
    public:
        bool set(int n, const char* str);
        void display() const;
};
```

main.cpp

```
int main() {

    int no;
    List list;

    cout << "List Processor\n==============" << endl;
    cout << "Enter number of items : ";
    cin >> no;

    list.set(no);
    list.display();
}
```

line::display

```
void Line::display() const {

    cout << this->num << ' ' << this->itemString << endl;

}
```

list.display (calls line.display, and line.display prints one instance of a line, if I call it 3 times, it will output 3 different types of data, each corresponding to an index of `listLine`)

```
void List::display() const {

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        this->listLine[i].display();
    }

}
```

Let's say that I populate `listLine` as so:

```
listLine[0].num = 1
listLine[0].itemString = ABC
listLine[1].num = 2
listLine[1].itemString = ZXC
listLine[2].num = 3
listLine[2].itemString = QWE
```

I know the above isn't proper C++ syntax, I'm just trying to illustrate the concept, show what data is inside `listLine`.

So far I have been able to print the contents of listLine as so:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    this->listLine[i].display();
}
```

Output of above

```
// reading values in
List Processor
==============
Enter number of items : 3
Enter line number : 1
Enter line string : ABC
Accepted
Enter line number : 2
Enter line string : ZXC
Accepted
Enter line number : 3
Enter line string : QWE
Accepted

// printing those values with the loop i posted
1 ABC
2 ZXC
3 QWE
1 
134514883 
-1217566436 Jm·Z·Èí¬¿-
134515757 
134514257 
134515633 0
-1218833660 ôZ·F·
```

Notice how the only valid data is `1 ABC`, `2 ZXC`, and `3 QWE` and after that it just prints gibberish?

I want to display only the valid data, but the display() function of List takes no paramaters, so how am I supposed to know which data in `listLine` is valid?

I only want to print the valid lines, in the above example, that is three, with the other 7 lines being nonsense.

Comment: Yes I will, sorry about that, it looks fairly cryptic upon second glance.

Comment: Why don't you store the number of `Line`s in your `List` `struct` (incrementing as you add and decrementing as you remove)? (I'm assuming that `std::list` is out-of-bounds for this assignment).

Comment: I cannot edit the structs. The data members and member functions are outlined in the assignment.

Comment: Initialize Line items that are not in use with invalid num like -1 or 0 and in Line::display() check for that value and do not print anything

Comment: List display is a loop that uses the line display, line display only issues one line from the array, so i have to loop it and call line display multiple times, problem is how to determine the loop number. I don't really understand what you're saying @Slava.

Comment: My suggestion is not to determine loop number, but Line objects that do not have correct data does not priont anything in their display method.

Comment: Ah that actually makes sense, so in line display I can check whether its valid, print if it is. That works, but I still need to determine how many lines to print in the list display function. Getting closer though.

Answer (score 0):

hm, the question changed a bit.

but my answer to the original question, below, is hint enough i think (for an exercise/homework question)

---

evidently the assignment calls for using nullterminated strings

that said, when you've finished with these assignments, use `std::string` (or `std::wstring`) to store strings

Comment: Will do, this is just an intro to OOP C++. My main problem is I can't access the datamembers of `line` from an array of `line` types in the `List` struct.

Comment: can you put another member in the List, where you can store the number passed in List::set(no)? Example: when you call List::set(no), then in its body, you store no in a variable inside List. So that when you call List::display(), you can use that variable as your upperbound when looping it

Comment: how about, like, using a zero line number after the last one (when there is room for it). okay i'm just restating my answer in more direct way. i think that was what the prof wished for you to figure out, perhaps.